# Из CSS Grid Layout в Таблицу

Tags: css, css3, css-grid

Нужно сделать так чтобы Footer начинался там где заканчивается Content.

То есть заставить сетку вести себя как таблица, чтобы новый ряд начинался там где заканчивается максимальный контент на предыдущем ряде.

[Проблема](http://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/GJVgOV)

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 120px 120px 120px;
  grid-template-areas: "....... header header" "sidebar content content" "footer  footer  footer";
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.header,
.footer {
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box header">Header</div>
  <div class="box sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="box content">Content
    <br /> More content than we had before so this column is now quite tall.</div>
  <div class="box footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
 
  grid-template-columns: 120px 120px 120px;
  grid-template-areas: "....... header header" "sidebar content content" "footer  footer  footer";
  background-color: #fd1;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.header,
.footer {
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box header">Header</div>
  <div class="box sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="box content">Content
    <br /> More content than we had before so this column is now
    <br /> More content than we had before so this column is now
    <br /> More content than we had before so this column is now
    <br /> More content than we had before so this column is now
    <br /> More content than we had before so this column is nowquite tall.</div>
  <div class="box footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```